# Abbreviations in Latin dictionaries, especially Lewis and Short

Tags: resource-request, abbreviations, dictionary

When reading [Lewis and Short online](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext%3a1999.04.0059)<sup>1</sup>, I have occasional trouble figuring out what the various abbreviations mean.
This includes authors and their works, but, more importantly to me, also other abbreviations.
At least this particular version does not seem to have any kind of preface, list of abbreviations or any such supporting material.
I believe many of the abbreviations are the same in many other dictionaries, so a list is likely to helpful outside L&S.

So, where can I find a list of abbreviations for L&S?
Lists for other similar dictionaries are also welcome, although my main interest is in L&S.
The list can be a webpage, a scan or transcription from a printed version, or anything else.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Also other online versions of the same dictionary are available.
See the [dictionary question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the abbreviations for Lewis & Short in the Latin Lexicon 'Numen' online:

> http://latinlexicon.org/LNS_abbreviations.php

First you will find the abbreviations of ancient authors and their works; then those of commonly used words and signs; last a catalogue of modern authors and their works referred to in the dictionary.

Here are the abbreviations for Liddell, Scott, Jones:

> http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Afrontmatter%3D5

For the Thesaurus Linguae Latinae:

> http://www.thesaurus.badw-muenchen.de/en/user-tools/abbreviations.html

The Oxford Latin Dictionary:

> http://www.oxfordscholarlyeditions.com/page/guide-to-the-dictionary

Here you will find general abbreviations and signs. Abbreviations of authors and their works are under the link "abbreviations" on the left.

Answer (score 6):

A digitized version of *Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon* (a.k.a. *Lewis & Short Lexicon*) is also available at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/harperslatindict00lewi), albeit not as easily searchable as an HTML webpage.

The beginning of the lexicon includes the:

- “Orthographical Index” on pages [v–vi](https://archive.org/stream/harperslatindict00lewi#page/n12/mode/1up),
- “Abbreviations Used in Referring to Ancient Authors and Their Works” on pages [vii–xi](https://archive.org/stream/harperslatindict00lewi#page/n14/mode/1up),
- “Catalogue of Editions of Ancient Authors, Books of Reference, etc.” on p. [xii–xiii](https://archive.org/stream/harperslatindict00lewi#page/n19/mode/1up), and
- “Other Abbreviations, Signs, etc.” on p. [xiv](https://archive.org/stream/harperslatindict00lewi#page/n21/mode/1up)

---

### References

Lewis, Charlton T.; Short, Charles. [*Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary Founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon.*](https://archive.org/details/harperslatindict00lewi) New York: American Book, 1879.