# Where can I read the introductions to the Latin Dictionaries

Tags: classical-latin, resource-request

If you want to read Lewis' introduction to his own dictionary it's not easy to find out where this is, same with Gaffiot, same with Labaigue and Georges.  (The Oxford Latin Dictionary is not available online.  There is said to be a subscription to Oxford Scholarly Editions, where it can be accessed but the link is broken and my emails have not been answered).  There at least is a link to the abbreviations in the Gaffiot dictionary here
http://www.prima-elementa.fr/Gaffiot/Gaffiot-1720.html
But there is no such link at prima-elementa.fr for the Lebaigue dictionary.  There are only links that start at A and end at Z here:
http://www.prima-elementa.fr/Lebaigue/
You would think that Perseus would have a link to an intro to the Lewis and Short dictionary but I have not been able to find it. Logion has all the great Latin dictionaries available online but I see no link to their introductions

https://logeion.uchicago.edu/lexidium

It stands to reason that if you're going to post a lexicon online with all sorts of strange abbreviations that you would explain those abbreviations as well.

Comment: If the dictionary is in the public domain, good chances a scan can be accessed using archive.org or GoogleBooks. One can simply write the dictionary name plus "archive" or "google books" in the search bar. here are scans of [L&S](https://archive.org/details/LewisAndShortANewLatinDictionary/) , and [Gaffiot](https://archive.org/details/FelixGaffiotDictionnaireIllustr.LatinFrancais/) for example.

Comment: @d_e Can you write that into an answer? It's short, but it doesn't matter as it does answer the question.

Comment: While were at it, I do not believe the following question is worthy of a new post in stackexchange but if you feel free to edit it, do you know what these number refer to in Gaffiot, here there is an 8 next to the def for pario: părĭō,8 pĕpĕrī, partum, părĭtūrus, ĕre, tr.,

Comment: Do you find [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/abbreviations-in-latin-dictionaries-especially-lewis-and-short) helpful? .

FWIW, I could not locate the edition of Lebaigue that that site uses. but I have this list of abbv. from a differnt edtion of Lebaigue, [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=13ZIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP7&hl=fr&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Yes, that helps.  Any idea about the numbers.  For example, here https://logeion.uchicago.edu/levitas  if you look at Gaffiot, he has the numbers 14 and 9.

Comment: @bobsmith76 those numbers are the *indice fréquentiel*, a number between 0 and 16 that indicates how frequently some words occur. 0 is the most frequent; only *sum*, *et* and *qui* have a zero score. This is an innovation in the 2016 digitization of the original 1934 Gaffiot. It's all explained in the preface. You can download the whole thing in PDF format [here](http://gerardgreco.free.fr/spip.php?article43&lang=fr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are several introductions that I could find:

- Lewis & Short, *A Latin Dictionary*:

  - [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Latin_Dictionary)
  - [Full text from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/LewisAndShortANewLatinDictionary/page/n1/mode/2up)
- Gaffiot, *Dictionnaire illustré Latin-Français*

  - [Wikisource](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Gaffiot_-_Dictionnaire_illustr%C3%A9_Latin-Fran%C3%A7ais.djvu/7)
  - [Full text from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/FelixGaffiotDictionnaireIllustr.LatinFrancais/page/n7/mode/2up)
- *Oxford Latin Dictionary*

  - [Editorial prelims available on oxfordscholarlyeditions.com](https://www.oxfordscholarlyeditions.com/page/editorial-prelims)
- Georges, *Ausführliches lateinisch-deutsches und deutsch-lateinisches Handwörterbuch*

  - [Full text from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ausfhrlicheslat01georgoog/page/n12/mode/2up)